# Blank AssertionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, error-handling, assertion

I'm running into this error quite a bit and I can't quite seem to understand why this error keeps popping up.

```
def addnumbers(number1, number2, base):
    sum = bin(int(number1,base)+int(number2,base))
    
    print(sum)
    
    return sum 
    
assert addnumbers("100011", "110011", 2) == "1010110"
assert addnumbers("4013", "4217", 8) == "10232"
addnumbers("100011","110011",2)
```

So I have this code that is a simple way of adding strings together and returning them in their base form, and right now I'm working on the hexadecimal part first. So the first assert line.

```
0b1010110
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-1102c03eff64> in <module>
     17     return sum
     18 
---> 19 assert addnumbers("100011", "110011", 2) == "1010110"
     20 assert addnumbers("4013", "4217", 8) == "10232"
     21 addnumbers("100011","110011",2)

AssertionError:
```

However, it returns with an error and a blank assertion error, and I'm not really sure where to start fixing my code when I don't really know how to fix the first assert line and giving me a blank error message. If anyone could give me any guidance to why the assertion error returns a blank that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Note what was printed out at the top vs what you're comparing against. They aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

To display the error text, you must explicitly set it:

```
assert addnumbers("100011", "110011", 2) == "1010110", 'My custom error message'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't catch the errors from assertions. All the assertions in the unittest module take a final parameter, msg, which is the message to be raised if the assertion fails. Put your debugging there if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

bin function will return string like this "0b..."
To fix your first assertation you can do like this

```
assert addnumbers("100011", "110011", 2) == "0b1010110"

# or 

assert addnumbers("100011", "110011", 2)[2:] == "1010110"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the returned value from the function (addnumbers) is string starting '0b', but you are comparing the returned value with the string without '0b'.

```
assert addnumbers("100011", "110011", 2) == "0b1010110"
```

The above code just prints the result, and no AssertionError occurs.